# MYSQL - Find records from one table which don't exist in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following two SQL tables (in MySQL):

`Users
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  | Luke |
| 2  | Mark |
| 3  | Lucy |
| 4  | Biff |`

`User category
| user_id | category_id |
|---------|-------------|
| 1       | 5           |
| 1       | 6           |
| 2       | 5           |
| 2       | 7           |
| 3       | 5           |`

I want users that are in User category but not if category id is 6.

In this case Mark and Lucy because Luke is in category 6 too and Biff has no category.

There is a way to do it without subquery and only in one query?

Comment: Is there any reason behind this *There is a way to do it without subquery and only in one query?*

Comment: No particular reason it's only for conceptual reasons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `group by` user_id and eliminate those rows where there is atleast one category_id of 6.

```
select uc.user_id,u.name
from user_category uc
join users u on uc.user_id = u.id
group by uc.user_id,u.name
having sum(case when category_id = 6 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(case when category_id = 6 then 1 END) <> 1`

Answer (score 0):

Join them and check for difference :

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_category ON (user_category.user_id = users.id) 
WHERE user_category.category_id <> 6
```

p.s. using group by is not effective, cuz it says to DB engine to do additional group by operation after gathering data.

Comment: I guess you missed to read the last line *There is a way to do it without subquery and only in one query?*

Comment: @Prdp, guys, I was wrtiting, suddenly clicked on submit (:

Comment: @num8er I want users that are in User category but not if category id is 6.